# Can I use RESTful web services with Oracle ADF

Tags: rest, oracle-adf

I want to develop and application with the Oracle ADF, but I want a RESTful web service that will allow for other clients (a desktop app, a mobile app, etc...). TO help me determine the best way to do this I have two questions:

1. Does the ADF have some easy way to create a REST service built into the application?
2. If not, can I create a JAX-RS web service and hook it up in the same container as the ADF application?

I am thinking that because of what the ADF is, it may be best not to try to create a service with it. If so, please alert me of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can build and consume REST from ADF Faces, please see below a step-by-step tutorial for ADF 12c:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53569_01/tutorials/tut_rest_ws/tut_rest_ws.html

This will work well for simple use cases, where there is not much complexity behind data entry screens.

However, you must keep in mind that ADF is most powerful when using Business Components and Bindings. Any other combination will decrease your productivity.

Answer (score 3):

Now with the release of jDeveloper 12.2.1 ADF comes with inbuilt REST Freamework which will solve all kinds of requirements(CRUD Operations, Custom method invocation, Paging, Data Consistency Check etc.)
The link for getting started with this

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/adf/develop/GUID-8F85F6FA-1A13-4111-BBDB-1195445CB630.htm#ADFFD589

will help a lot in getting started with REST and ADF.
For getting into more advanced features please follow this link

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/adf/develop/GUID-589F3905-5A8D-402D-B2D2-3BEEB2D7DDD4.htm#ADFFD54082

this will help in implementing all the other features in the ADF way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can build REST service on top of ADF components, here's a fresh tutorial showing how to proceed with many Java technologies : http://multikoop.blogspot.com/2014/06/create-restful-services-on-top-of-adf.html and also http://waslleysouza.com.br/en/2014/10/expose-adf-bc-restful-web-service/

Comment: The links you are posting here are ways of exposing existing business services written with ADF BC as REST webservices. Not sure it makes sense to build the ADF BC if you intend to expose rest to your UI.

Answer (score 0):

With JDeveloper 12.2.1 release, an easy way to create REST services has been provided. Using this feature, you can expose the entity objects of your choice as REST resources and then consume them easily via the DC palette.

Take a look at this blog which provides some insight into the same:
http://stick2code.blogspot.in/2015/11/creating-adfbc-rest-services-new.html